# Firebase query is showing inaccurate results

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

**Query**

I made this query to search the documents based on *doorNumber* and *merchantId* which should be present in the *merchants* list in the document field and also prepared indexing but it's not working and showing that there are 0 customers.

```
final customersRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('customerDB')
        .where('merchants', arrayContains: merchantId)
        .where('address.doorNumber', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchKey)
        .where('address.doorNumber', isLessThan: searchKey + 'z')
        .orderBy('address.doorNumber')
        .orderBy('name', descending: true)
        .limit(limit);
```

**Firebase data model**
[image]
[image]

Comment: is that the correct way to access doorNumber like ```"address.doorNumber"```? Its String after all.

Comment: but it is the map. To access the map we need use dot.

Comment: I don' t think so, I usually use ```[key]``` to access map element, like ```data['address']['doorNumber']```

Comment: you can try it in firebase query builder.

Answer (score 0):

Changed z to ~ then it works but we can only search by prefix.

```
final customersRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('customerDB')
        .where('merchants', arrayContains: merchantId)
        .where('address.doorNumber', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchKey)
        .where('address.doorNumber', isLessThan: searchKey + '~')
        .orderBy('address.doorNumber')
        .orderBy('name', descending: true)
        .limit(limit);
```